# iCloud Drive keeps writing to hard drive

Tags: windows-10, icloud

I have iCloud Drive installed on a Windows 10 machine since 6 month or so. A few days ago, when the computer became slow, I discovered that iCloud Drive makes write accesses to my hard drive with 2-4MB/s all the time without me doing anything in the cloud directory on any machine. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I logged out from the iCloud, saw that I ran low on disk space, freed some space and the hard drive access looks normal since I'm logged in again. This is hardly a satisfying explanation, but solved the issue for me.